# Issue when starting up Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet, browser

After trying both Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, I decided to go ahead with Chrome and uninstalled Firefox.

After that uninstallation, I have had an issue with Chrome. Whenever I start the browser, it takes about 20 to 30 seconds until my main homepage loads. During that time, at the bottom left a little popup appears which says `Proxy auflösen`, which means something like "resolve proxy". What could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that I wasn't very detailed in googling this issue. I found a solution [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=de&answer=106010), for anyone who's interested in:

- Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Settings.
- Click Show advanced settings.
- In the "Network" section, click Change proxy settings. This
  will open the Internet Properties dialog.
- Click LAN    settings    .
- Deselect the "Automatically detect settings" checkbox.